# Dojo/Dijit declaring controls

Tags: dojo

What is the difference between the two declarations and will one (or has one) been discontinued?

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" data-dojo-props="title:'Confirm Deletion'">
...
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" title="Confirm Deletion">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-` is an an HTML5 notation.  Technically speaking `<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" title="Confirm Deletion">` is invalid HTML, because the HTML spec does not define the attributes `dojoType` and other attributes that are properties on widgets.  The result is that when you open files in an html editor, the html editor will highlight the markup as invalid.

The HTML5 spec recognized the use of custom attributes and added `data-` attributes.  HTML5 editors will accept any attribute begininnng with `data-` as valid.

Going forward, you should use the HTML5 notation.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" data-dojo-props="title:'Confirm Deletion'">
```

Comment: For reference, the data-dojo-* properties came into use as of dojo 1.6.

Comment: I have found `data-dojo-props="...` in some instances not to work, hence I have use `dojoData` all over my project. Will this type of deceleration be discontinued in the future? And is there anything coming down the pipe (browsers/specifications) that would lead to possible conflicts in the future?

Comment: What version of dojo are you using?  The earliest dojo parser support for the legacy notation would be removed is 2.0.  Web browsers will have to support non-HTML5 web pages for a long time.

Comment: I'm using 1.6.1 with dojango at them moment